# Alternative to Photosync to sync pictures into Picasa

Tags: sync, photos

The version of Photosync I have installed fails to upload pictures after I take a few dozen of them in a short period of time. Is there an alternative app that will work and not take too much memory on my poor old 2.3.5 phone?

The Google+ app is too heavy for my phone.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, the [Google+ app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus&hl=en) sounds like it has the functionality you're looking for. Within the app, press `Menu -> Settings -> Instant Upload` and turn the feature on. This will upload them to Google+ to a folder only you can see, and as Google+ and Picasa albums are the same, they'll be available on your Picasa account as well!

Comment: Thee Google+ app is too heavy for my poor phone.

Comment: I'll try this two alternative: "Photo Auto Uploader" / "Picasa Uploader"

Comment: if it works, repost as an answer so those looking later can find what you did! :)